# Online classes for learning Classical Latin

Tags: classical-latin, resource-request

Does anyone have any recommendations on online video classes for learning Classical Latin? I have bought courses on Udemy.com, for example, for web development and saw that there are a few different [courses available for Latin](https://www.udemy.com/topic/latin-language/) as well.

Has anyone bought and taken those? What did you think? Did you use something similar through another site like Udemy.com?

Answer (score 1):

I can personally recommend TelePaideia -- my teachers for three separate classes were fantastic. I made friends and contacts while I furthered my Latin education.

My teacher (Ilsa) plugged her own website with online classes: https://www.habesnelac.com/. I attest that the people working on this site are experienced speakers of latin.